# Python cannot find flask_script

Tags: flask, flask-script

I am running a basic Flask application which uses flask script, but when I move the environment from Cloud 9 to a local installation on my Mac, it stops working. I get the following error.

```
ImportError: No module named 'flask_script'
```

I am using virtualenv, and I have installed flask script in the environment, and also to tried to reinstall it as pointed out in following posts about this topic:

[Python cannot find dateutil.relativedelta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418636/python-cannot-find-dateutil-relativedelta)

[No module named flask_script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39059847/no-module-named-flask-script)

[Python can't find my Flask script under virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747805/python-cant-find-my-flask-script-under-virtualenv)

My manage.py which causes the problem looks like this:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

from flask_script import Manager, Server
from flask.ext.migrate import MigrateCommand
from flask_app import app

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

manager.add_command('runserver', Server(
    use_debugger = True,
    use_reloader = True,
    host = os.getenv('IP', '0.0.0.0'),
    port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 5000))
    )
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

When I run

```
pip freeze
```

to see what is installed, Flask_Script shows:

```
alembic==0.8.7
click==6.6
Flask==0.11.1
Flask-Markdown==0.3
Flask-Migrate==2.0.0
Flask-Script==2.0.5
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
Flask-Uploads==0.2.1
Flask-WTF==0.12
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8
lxml==3.6.0
Mako==1.0.4
Markdown==2.6.6
MarkupSafe==0.23
py-bcrypt==0.4
pymongo==3.2.2
PyMySQL==0.7.6
python-docx==0.8.6
python-editor==1.0.1
python-slugify==1.2.1
requests==2.10.0
SQLAlchemy==1.0.15
Unidecode==0.4.19
Werkzeug==0.11.11
WTForms==2.1
```

The flask script documentation says it should be imported like this:

```
from flask.ext.script import Manager
```

As I understand it, this is an older method, which is replaced by the one I am using. But anyway, using flask.ext.script produces the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a circular dependency problem.

Have a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19467445/1570104 where this kind of problem is nicely explained.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- Try use File/Settings/Python Interpreter / "+" / find "flask-script" (install)
  or
- pip install Flask-script